# alasql sheetname with special characters

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel, alasql

How can I export an excel files with multiple sheets with special characters in sheet name? 
For example, I tried this but the file cannot be opened:

```
window.saveFile = function saveFile () {
        var data1 = [{a:1,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
    var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
    var opts = [{sheetid:'Good1&2',header:true},{sheetid:'Two',header:false}];
    var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("MyAwesomeData.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data1,data2]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, I need to escape the sheetid in xml since it's generated in xml format to the excel.

Here is the source: http://jsfiddle.net/ry8fq0dL/125/

```
 window.saveFile = function saveFile () {
var data1 = [{a:1,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
    var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
    var opts = [{sheetid:"One1&amp;2",header:true},{sheetname:'Two',header:false}];
    var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("restest344b.xlsx",?) FROM ?',
                     [opts,[data1,data2]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library is updated so I don't have to escape the character now.

```
> http://jsfiddle.net/nvhoang115/L2gmkx1b/2/
```